# creating a range from named range offset

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA, so please be patient with me :)

I created a program to loop through the columns in a named range and, if the cell is not blank, transfer
and organize certain information from that column into a table on another sheet. I seem to be encountering an error with the offset ranges. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you!

```
Dim PTMsht As Worksheet
    Set PTMsht = Sheets("PTM")
Dim TRNsht As Worksheet
    Set TRNsht = Sheets("LIST")


Dim TRN_lastrow As Long
    TRN_lastrow = TRNsht.Range("J" & TRNsht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Dim PTM_lastrow As Long
    PTM_lastrow = PTMsht.Range("D" & PTMsht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim col As Range

    For Each col In PTMsht.Range("DOC_TITLE")

     If col.Value <> vbnullstring Then
            TRNsht.Range("K" & TRN_lastrow & ":K" & (TRN_lastrow + (PTM_lastrow - 9))).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(PTMsht.Range(col.Offset(9, 0), col.Offset(PTM_lastrow, 0)).Value)
            TRNsht.Range("D" & TRN_lastrow & ":I" & (TRN_lastrow)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(PTMsht.Range(col.Offset(1, 0).Address, col.Offset(6, 0).Address))
            TRNsht.Range("J" & TRN_lastrow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(PTMsht.Range(col.Offset(0, 0), col.Offset(0, 0)))
            TRNsht.Range("B" & TRN_lastrow & ":C" & (TRN_lastrow + 135)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(PTMsht.Range("D15:E" & PTM_lastrow))
        End If
Next col
```

Comment: You seem to be encountering an error or you are encountering an error? If the latter, please describe the message and when it occurs.

Comment: I'm only getting the value in the first cell of the range that I am trying to duplicate instead of the range: 
         Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(PTMsht.Range(col.Offset(9, 0), col.Offset(PTM_lastrow, 0)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error you're receiving. Also, Offsets look a little odd - can you edit the question to explain what you're trying to do with the data transfer (ie from where to where).

Comment: femwill,  visit these and try single-stepping with F8, and pasting "?"code to the immediate window.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.item
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/immediate-window
I suspect you need to reverse your main loop operations to  
`PTMsht.Range...Copy _ TRNsht.Range...PasteSpecial(,,,True)` form. And not need WorksheetFunctions at all.